# Kriging along perpendicular transects

Tags: kriging

I collected data along two perpendicular transects (in a "+" shape) and would like to create a prediction surface map with kriging. What form of kriging (method, parameters, etc.) is appropriate to better model this particular spatial distribution of the data?

Comment: this seems like a duplicate of your other question...

Comment: The question was placed on hold and I was asked to rephrase it. I have deleted the earlier post. Sorry for the hassle!

Comment: This doesn't seem phrased any differently from the old one though...

Comment: And we've still not established what you've tried, and what was wrong with that. I can do kriging on data with a "+"-shaped sampling pattern and I get perfectly reasonable estimates and SEs.

Comment: Please do not delete questions and then re-ask them as an alternative to editing to improve them.